# Why can't a spin-1 particle decay into two identical spin-0 particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

**I've got this far:**

Suppose a spin-1 particle with $j$,$l$,$s$ decays into a system of two identical spin-0 particles with $J$,$L$,$S$.

The RHS must have total spin $S=0$, so $J=L$ which must be even since the particles are Bosons and their states must be symmetric in their exchange.

Then by conservation and addition of angular momenta, the LHS must have $L=J=j=\left\{\begin{array} \.l-1,l,l+1 &\text{ if }l\neq0 \\ 1 &\text{ if }l=0 \end{array}\right.$.

Mistakes are likely.

**Two possible ways to proceed (but I can't motivate either):**

1. Can I choose to take $l=0$ for some reason?
2. I know (I think) that a system of two identical Bosons has to have $l$ even, because of symmetry of their wavefunctions under exchange of the two particles. Does the value of $l$ for a single Boson also have to be even? If so, can I then somehow rule out the $j=l\neq 0$ case and get a contradiction?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that your decay does not violate parity, and let us take the example of  strong interaction process involving [mesons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson).

Looking at this [wiki paragraph and array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson#Spin.2C_orbital_angular_momentum.2C_and_total_angular_momentum), you will understand that each meson has a total angular moment, and a parity, noted $J^P$, and there are several possibilities for $S$ and $L$, for a given  $J^P$ ($J^P$ is a characteristic of the particle)

Let us precise the example with the decay of the neutral [rho meson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rho_meson)  $\rho^0$ into 2  [pions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion).

The rho meson has $J^P=1^-$, so we see in the wiki array, that $S=1$ and $L=0$ is a possibility, while $S=1$ and $L=2$ is an other possibility.
Each of the pion has $J^P=0^-$, and we see that the only possibility is $S=0$ and $L=0$, for each pion.

We decide to prepare a rho meson in the state $S=1,L=0$

A key point is that, even if each pion itself has $L=0$, the system of 2 pions may have a relative orbital momentum $L_r$, so that the total angular momentum of the 2 pions system (remembering that $S_{TOT}=0$) is then $J=L_r$. By conservation of the total angular momentum, this gives $L_r=1$

An other point is that, in the strong interaction, the parity is conserved, so we have :

$(-1) = (-1)(-1)(-1)^{L_r}$, which says that $L_r$ is odd, which is not in contradiction with the fact that $L_r=1$

But, in fact, the decay $\rho^0 \to \pi^+, \pi ^-$ is possible, while the decay $\rho^0 \to \pi^o, \pi^0$ is not possible. Why ?

There is one more constraint, in the case where the $2$ final particles are identical, the relative orbital momentum $L_r$ must corresponds to the statistical nature of the particles, so it has to be even for bosons, and odd for fermions.

Now, pions are bosons, so, in the decay $\rho^0 \to \pi^o, \pi^0$, $L_r$ must be even, which is in contradiction with the above conclusions ($L_r=1$). So, this decay is not allowed.

The decay $\rho^0 \to \pi^+, \pi ^-$ is allowed, because the particles are different, so a odd relative orbital momentum $L_r=1$ is allowed (to be rigourous, you have also to check other conservation laws, like charge, C-Parity, G-Parity, and so on (see [mesons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson))

Comment: I understand this specific example, but the question posed was far more general: Firstly it referred to any spin-1 and spin-0 particles, so there is some loss in generality in choosing the initial parity and angular momentum values of the particles. One could be chosen with $S=1$, $J^P=2^+$ (from the table) for example and then I don't think the argument about requiring $L_r$ even for bosons would still work. Secondly, the question did not allow the assumption that parity alone is conserved, so that argument would fail too.

Comment: @UtterlyConfused : Yes, this is correct, a [tensor meson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson#Types_of_meson), with $J^P=2^+$, may decay (in a strong interaction) into two identical particles, for instance the meson particle [f2(1565)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mesons#Summary_table), may decay into 2 $\pi^0$, see [particle data group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2012/listings/rpp2012-list-f2-1565.pdf), page $3$. So, there is not a general answer to your question, each case must be studyed, and we have to apply all needed conservation laws, to have a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You know that s=1 since it was given in the question, so you know that L = J = j = l+1. Moreover, L must be even as you stated so l must be odd. If you could make the assumption that l must be even then you would have a contradiction, but I don't know if you can. Did you get any further with this?